# alert dialog closing touch any where in the screen with out press yes or no

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using alert dialog in my android app, which has a YES and a NO button.

I want the alert to close on clicking either YES or NO, but it is closing touch everywhere in the screen how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)